Custom Codeigniter Rule to capture a field that begins with 'X'
I need to create a rule which checks that a form field has been submitted which is either of the following:
'year0', 'year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4', 'year5'
Below is an example of post data. In this example the validation should pass as I have 2 fields passed, one 'year1' and another 'year3'
Array
(
    [name] => Test Submission
    [year1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1281
        )

    [year3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1345
        )
)

so far I have this but it isn't working
$yearPost = ['year0', 'year1', 'year2', 'year3', 'year4', 'year5'];
$multiYears = false;
foreach ($yearPost as $field) {
  if (array_key_exists($field, $this->input->post())) {
     $multiYears = true;
     break;
   }
}

if ($multiYears === false) {
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'required|numeric');
}


Your script breaks the loop on the first encounter of a whitelisted value -- this does not mean that there are "multiple" years submitted. Do you want to filter the submission's keys and count how many where whitelisted? Filter a flat, associative array by the keys in another flat, associative array or Use an array of keys to filter another array, keeping the "order" or How to filter an associative array comparing keys with values in an indexed array?

Generally speaking, the fact that you have appended numbers to each of the year fields may be a symptom that you should have used array syntax in your form's field names.
